# PHP Update always update empty string

Tags: php, sql

let me explain the code I'm getting data from the db and display the data in text input then when the user make changes I get the user input and update the table however when it update it update to empty data

```
<?php
echo "<form action='' method='get'>";

echo "<td class='data'><input type='product_name' id='product_name' value=" . $row['product_name'] . "> </td>";
echo "<td class='data'><input type='products_price' id='products_price' value=" . $row['products_price'] . "> </td>";
echo "<td class='data'><input type='products_desc' id='products_desc' value=" . $row['products_desc'] . "> </td>";

echo "</form>";

echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "<form action='' method='POST'>
                 <input name='update' type='submit' value='Update' style='margin-left: 720px'>
                </form>";
$product_name = isset($_GET['product_name']) ? $_GET['product_name'] : '';

$products_desc = isset($_GET['products_desc']) ? $_GET['products_desc'] : '';

$products_price = isset($_GET['products_price']) ? $_GET['products_price'] : '';
if (isset($_POST["update"])) {




    $sql1 = "UPDATE tbl_products SET products_desc='" . $products_desc . "',product_name='" . $product_name . "',products_price='" . $products_price . "' WHERE products_id='" . $product_id . "'";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    echo "yess";

}
?>
```

Comment: you've explained what you're doing but you didn't tell us what's wrong or what's not working or if there are any errors......etc. etc. etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable” and “Notice: Undefined index”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input` elements have no `name` attribute, so things like `$_GET['product_name']` will always be empty.  The `name` attribute is the key in the key/value pair sent to the server.

Additionally, the `type` attributes are all broken.  (Though I suspect the browser is automatically "correcting" that by defaulting to a text input.)

Add the `name` attribute (and fix `type`):

```
<input type='text' name='product_name' id='product_name' ...
```

**Additionally**, you have **two** forms.  So when you click your button, *that* form doesn't submit any of the inputs.  Because they're in a different form.

Put them all into the same `form`, and decide whether you want to use `GET` or `POST` (since your server-side code is going to need to know that).

Answer (score 0):

You defined your data form in one form tag and submit form in the another form tag:

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
     <input name='update' type='submit' value='Update' style='margin-left: 720px'>
</form>

echo "<form action='' method='get'>";

echo "<td class='data'><input type='product_name' id='product_name' value=" . $row['product_name'] . "> </td>";
echo "<td class='data'><input type='products_price' id='products_price' value=" . $row['products_price'] . "> </td>";
echo "<td class='data'><input type='products_desc' id='products_desc' value=" . $row['products_desc'] . "> </td>";

echo "</form>";
```

When you submit your first form but your data is on another form

this is what is wrong